# Testing ext3 filesystem on embedded device

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, testing

My set up:
An embedded device with flash memory on it. 
Flash is partitioned into ext3 filesystem partitions. 
Have busybox on it.

My Goal:
To uncover errors /bugs/ problems on ext3 filesystems.

Linux version:
Not the latest and greatest: linux-2.6.31

What tests should I run to uncover potential problems in the ext3 filesystem?

Comment: "Using it" is a good way of testing.

Comment: @ChrisDown But that's not good enough!

Comment: `fsck.ext3 -f`? If absent from your system, find or build a suitable binary. Worst case you'll have to cross-compile one.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking to seek out filesystem *bugs* or filesystem *errors*?

Comment: @ChrisDown Both actually.

Comment: Maybe a little `iozone` action will help.

Comment: Given how much `ext3` has spread and how much it's used (including enterprise environments), you may be very hard-pressed to find bugs in the code. I've managed hundreds of `ext3` filesystems and the only issues I ever encountered were due to *one incident* where bad (non-ECC) RAM corrupted data before it was committed to disk. And that wasn't even due to the filesystem. Have you considered looking at the kernel Changelog for the filesystem?

Comment: The filesystem folks of the Linux kernel have some tools for injecting faults and checking scaffolding for filesystems. I'm not into that area, but I've seen such mentioned. Look around at [kernelnewbies](http://www.kernelnebies.org) or the various filesystem trees on [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org).

Answer (score 0):

A good stress test could shake out some filesystem bugs. Checkout the stress tests available at the Linux Test Project. LTP's tests are listed [here](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/tooltable.php) and there is a file system section.

As far as filesystem errors, try tests that simulate an unexpected power failure while a file is being written. You can do this by writing a script that continuously writes data to a file and then simulate the power failure by pulling the plug or doing a forced unmount of the file system (i.e "umount -f").

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LTP (Linux Test Project)](http://ltp.sourceforge.net), a collection of utilities to test all sorts of Linux subsystems (including filesystems). And yes, this is used routinely by the kernel developers, so unless you dig in and complete/extend some of the tests (or run an unusual setup) I guess you'll not find much in the way of unknown bugs. But knock yourself out.